# How does WordPress create URLs that Apache knows about?

Tags: permalinks, urls, apache

When you create a page in WordPress, it's just an entry in a database table; there's no actual file at that location. However I can create a file at that location myself and it will steal the page away from WordPress. I delete the file and it seamlessly goes back to the WordPress page.

I'm just curious about how this is achieved. Presumably some communication is happening between WordPress and Apache(?).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually there is no communication happening between Apache and WordPress. The "magic" is happening in Apache `mod_rewrite` rules.

For a standard WordPress installation, you have the following rules in `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Notice this line: `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`
Here, we are telling Apache to internally redirect any URL request to `/index.php`.

***Unless:*** this line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` becomes false. That means, with adding this `RewriteCond` with the above `RewriteRule`, we are telling Apache to send all requests to `/index.php`, but ***not if it's an existing file***.

***Also, when*** this line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` becomes false. That means, with adding this `RewriteCond` with the above `RewriteRule`, we are telling Apache to send all request to `/index.php`, but ***not if it's an existing directory***.

So in the end, unless it's an existing file or an existing directory, Apache is internally sending all other requests to `/index.php`.

So as you see, no communication is happening between Apache & WordPress. Apache is deciding everything itself and we are telling it to do so using `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` directives.

Read more about [`mod_rewrite` HERE](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: This is great. I understand perfectly. I've looked at the default .htaccess file many times and never bothered to analyse it. Thank you!

Comment: This is a design pattern called front controller. Note that it redirects all non-existing urls to index.php, this means that if you type out the full path to your functions.php file, the frontcontroller won't work and the website will serve functions.php. This is why you'll often see WordPress plugin and theme files start with `if ( !defined(‘ABSPATH’)) exit;`

Comment: Yes I have seen that in plugins but did not understand its purpose. So, if `!defined(‘ABSPATH’)` evaluates to true, it means something other than WordPress is trying to access the script (because ABSPATH is defined in wp-config.php), and therefore it should ignore that request. Is that correct?

Comment: @matt That's correct. Although I'd not say that "something other than WordPress". Because you can define `ABSPATH` in any other PHP script as well, so it'll allow other scripts on your own server. What it'll not allow is the direct access of that file from outside of your server (say from  browser). Because by accessing that file directly, users are in no way able to define `ABSPATH`.

Comment: This is really great to know. I constantly worry about security and I'll be able to take advantage of this right away. Thank you!